# gldrawpixel rgb value from a array

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, freeglut

I have a three dimensional array

```
unsigned int window_RGBData[3][640][480];
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(window_Width,window_Height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, window_RGBData);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

it only shows me a black screen, no matter what the values in the array. The array is like this, dimension 1 is red, dimension 2 is green and third is blue.
When I use **gl_unsinged_byte** instead of int I get lines of black and white(if all array is 255). So it is reading from the array.
But I think I am not able to specify the correct format of the array to opengl. I can use the

```
glBegin(GL_POINT)
// code here
glEnd
```

but for a specific reason this way is out of bounds.

Any ideas on how to specify the format here in gldrawpixels function or any other way.

initialization etc:

```
int Image::OpenGLShow(){
// Display onscreen
    int argc=1;
    char* argv[1];
    argv[0]=strdup("Helloguys");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    window_Height=Height;
    window_Width= Width;
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(Width, Height);
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL glDrawPixels demo");

  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glutMainLoop();
    return 0; 
}
```

**EDIT:**
I believe the problem is with the values I am putting in my array. Now this is how the array is being populated:

```
for(int i =0;i<200;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<200;j++){
            // rgb values at i*j point on screen. 
            window_RGBData[0][i][j]=red_value;  // 0-255
            window_RGBData[1][i][j]=green_value;
            window_RGBData[2][i][j]=blue_value;
        }
    }
```

So basically I was assuming that the gldrawpixels method will combine the three together and display the pixel, depending on the format I provided. Which defininetly is not what gldrawpixels is doing. So should I change the way the array is being populated or change the formate value?

Comment: Can you show the setup of your opengl context?  Specifically, setting your display mode?

Comment: i edited the question.. it must be noted that i have tried drawing a triangle using glbegin() and glend() and it showed properly..

Comment: "dimension 1 is red, dimension 2 is blue and third is green" -- where did you get that idea from? It's (probably!) not related to your problem, but it sure is a Misunderstanding The Basics.

Comment: my bad its in rgb fomat.. but I was talking about how my array is populated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That array is too big to put on the stack.

Increase your stack size, allocate it on the heap, or try something smaller:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>

const unsigned int W = 200;
const unsigned int H = 200;

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    unsigned int data[H][W][3];
    for( size_t y = 0; y < H; ++y )
    {
        for( size_t x = 0; x < W; ++x )
        {
            data[y][x][0] = ( rand() % 256 ) * 256 * 256 * 256;
            data[y][x][1] = ( rand() % 256 ) * 256 * 256 * 256;
            data[y][x][2] = ( rand() % 256 ) * 256 * 256 * 256;
        }
    }

    glDrawPixels( W, H, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( W, H );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even if i reduce the window and array size, its still only showing me a black screen

Comment: So the program I posted is giving you a black screen?

Comment: Array dimensions are mixed here as well. With totally random data it is not visible, though.

Comment: okay i used your values in my array and it is displayng. But if i put 255 in the array it displays a black screen.. Guess the problem is in the way I am populating my array.. basically thats how i am thinking data[0][0][0] contains the red value for the 0*0 pixel, data[1][0][0] contains green and the third dimension contains blue. But the way you are populating the array. Guess my understanding of how opengl is rendering my array is wrong.

Comment: can you explain why you are populating the array as you are.. Plus lets say I want to populate it fully with 100,100,100 rgb then how will I populate it?

Comment: I elaborated my previous answer with some more explicit details on filling the buffer. HTH

Comment: change 255 to 256

Comment: and swap x , y in Array or W , H

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
unsigned int window_RGBData[3][640][480];
```

try

```
unsigned int window_RGBData[480][640][3];
```

and of course fill the buffer accordingly.

Multidimensional arrays in C(++) are merely a syntactic sugar. `window_RGBData` is passed to `glDrawPixels` as a pointer. It points to an area in memory, and `glDrawPixels` interprets the values there according to the `format` and `type` parameters.
In the current case the values should be unsigned integers, and their order is the following:

```
row1_column1.r row1_column1.g row1_column1.b
row1_column2.r row1_column2.g row1_column2.b
...
row1_column640.r row1_column640.g row1_column640.b
row2_column1.r row2_column1.g row2_column1.b
row2_column2.r row2_column2.g row2_column2.b
...
row2_column640.r row2_column640.g row2_column640.b
...
row480_column1.r row480_column1.g row480_column1.b
row480_column2.r row480_column2.g row480_column2.b
...
row480_column640.r row480_column640.g row480_column640.b
```

See also http://mycodelog.com/tag/gldrawpixels/

Be aware of the alignment as well:

> width × height pixels are read from memory, starting at location data.
>   By default, these pixels are taken from adjacent memory locations,
>   except that after all width pixels are read, the read pointer is
>   advanced to the next four-byte boundary. The four-byte row alignment
>   is specified by glPixelStore with argument GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, and it
>   can be set to one, two, four, or eight bytes.

Source: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml

An alternative way of declaring and filling the buffer using a single dimensional array:

```
unsigned window_RGBData[640 * 480 * 3]; // 640 mod 4 == 0
...
window_RGBData[3 * (y * 640 + x) + 0] = ColorYouWantAtXY(x, y).red;
window_RGBData[3 * (y * 640 + x) + 1] = ColorYouWantAtXY(x, y).green;
window_RGBData[3 * (y * 640 + x) + 2] = ColorYouWantAtXY(x, y).blue;
```

Note that here we exploited 640 modulo 4 == 0 and therefore had no issues with the alignment.

Comment: that explains a lot of things, so thanks to you my code is actually working, but I had to change the array to the dimensions you specified and make window_RGBData a GLuByte instead of unsinged int. So for further understanding why GluByte works whereas unsigned int or GLuInt displays only a black screen(I did change mode to gl_unsinged_int when needed).